# ReactNative useEffect Parent to Child data refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

useEffect is causing me some issues with fetching data and being able to reload the popup with the latest data, its not being updated.

1. ScreenA fetches data and loads the data into the SamplePopup - OK
2. SamplePopup is able to get and render this data - OK
3. On SamplePopup you press a button to trigger a refresh back on to ScreenA - OK
4. ScreenA fetches new data (OK), but now the SamplePopup does not get this new data - FAIL

Any ideas on how to get SamplePopup the latest data from its parent ScreenA?

```
const ScreenA = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    refreshing: false,
    fruits: [],
    vegetables: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveData();
  }, [data.refreshing]);

  retrieveData = async () => {
    let incomingFruits = [];
    let incomingVegetables = [];

    try {
      const response = await fetch('api/fruits');
      let json = await response.json();

      incomingFruits = json.fruits;
    } catch (error) {

    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('api/vegetables');
      let json = await response.json();

      incomingVegetables = json.vegetables;
    } catch (error) {
      
    }

    setData({
      refreshing: false,
      fruits: incomingFruits,
      vegetables: incomingVegetables
    });
  }

  const refresh = () => {
    retrieveData()
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      {
        showPopup ? 
        <SamplePopup 
          onPress={() => refresh()}
          data={data}
          showPopup={showPopup}
          refreshing={data ? data.refreshing : false} /> 
        : null
      }
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setShowPopup(true)}>
        <View >
          <Text style={{paddingLeft: 5}}>Show Popup</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

// SamplePopup

const SamplePopup = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('data refresh')
    console.log(props.data)
  }, []);

  onRefresh = () => {
    props.onPress('REFRESH');
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      animationIn="slideInRight"
      animationOut="slideOutRight"
      isVisible={props.showPopup}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onRefresh()}>
          <View >
            <Text style={{paddingLeft: 5}}>Fetch new data</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the suggestion here, as it is a bit long and includes code

data is getting updated , it just date you are trying the log inside

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('data refresh')
    console.log(props.data)
  }, []);
```

The callback to this useEffect will run only once after first render.
try printing the value outside useEffect. You would be getting the updated data.

Thanks. Let me know if it fixed your problem.

Comment: It might be able to print but I need to process the data and it will say too many re-renders infinite loop.